# Detecting and Replacing Outliers

Tags: python, machine-learning, outliers

In my mind, there are multiple ways to treat dataset outliers

```
> -> Delete data
> -> Transforming using log or Bin
> -> using mean  median
> -> Test separately
```

I have a dataset of around 50000 observations and each observation has quite some outlier values (some variable have small amount of outliers some has 100-200 outliers) so excluding data is not the one I'm looking for as it causing me to loose a huge chunk of data.

I read somewhere that using mean and median is for artificial outliers but in my case I think the outliers are Natural

[image]

I was actually about to use median to get rid of the outliers and then using mean to fill in missing values but it doesn't seem ok, however I did use it neverthless with this code

```
median = X.median()
std =X.std()
outliers = (X - median).abs() > std
X.outliers = np.nan
X.fillna(median, inplace = True)
```

it did lower the overfitting of just one model logistic regression but still gives 100% on Random Forest and the shape of graph changed from 
[image] 
to this 
[image]
 So I'm really confuse what technique to use? I tried replacing 5th and 95th percentile of data as well but it didn't work as well. Should I bin the data present in each column from 1-10? Also should I normalize or standardize my data before applying any model? Any guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check robust statistics.

I would suggest to check the Huber's method / winsorization, which you also [have in Python.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html)

For Hypothesis testing you have Wilcoxon signed ranked test and I think Mann-Whitney test

Comment: Thank you for answering. I read about all the techniques and robust sounds the best because of outliers, will try that. Isn't winsorization the same as 5th and 95th method mentioned above? The outliers gets removed using this method but the data still shows 97-100% accuracy